# What is Relativistic Navier-Stokes Equation Through Einstein Notation?

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

[Navier-Stokes equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/navier-stokes_equations) is non-relativistic, what is relativistic Navier-Stokes equation through Einstein notation?

Comment: For starters, check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_solution).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730551/226902

Answer (score 15):

Are you referring to the exact relativistic equivalent to Navier-Stokes equation or a more general Dissipative Relativistic Hydrodynamics Equation?

The "relativistic equivalent to Navier-Stokes equation" would be something like this:

There would be an energy momentum tensor with the following form:

$T_{\mu\nu} = (e+p)u_\mu u_\nu - p g_{\mu\nu} + \tau_{\mu\nu}$

with the viscous stress tensor given by:

$\tau_{\mu\nu}= -\eta \left[(\partial_\mu u_\nu+\partial_\nu u_\mu) - u_\mu u^\alpha \partial_\alpha u_\nu - u_\nu u^\alpha\partial_\alpha u_\mu\right] - (\zeta - \frac{2}{3}\eta)\left[\partial_\alpha u^\alpha\right](g_{\mu\nu}-u_\mu u_\nu) $

And the Conservation of Energy and Momentum would lead to:

$\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu}=0$

The idea is to try to transpose the expressions you use in usual non-relativistic NS equation and fix the terms via positivity of entropy production. The relativistic Euler equation can be obtained setting $\tau_{\mu\nu}=0$, although some effort must be made to recover the Euler equation, it can be done.

The reference that I used was [L. D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz, Fluid Mechanics, chap. XV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750627670)

I'm asking this because this is not the only formulation of dissipative relativistic hydrodynamics, and it`s not necessarily the best one.

P.S.:

I'm using $g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$, $u^\mu$ refers to the 4-velocity of the fluid, $e$ and $p$ refer to the proper energy density and the pressure, $\zeta$ and $\eta$ would refer to the bulk and shear viscosity.

Edit: Sorry, more typo corrections